# Jssor Slider GoTo() for Thumbnails

Tags: jssor

First of all: Great Plugin. Thank you!

1) For any slider with thumbnails for example Image Gallery), when selecting a specific thumbnail, it appears to use `PlayTo()`. 
How would I use `GoTo()` - instead of `PlayTo()` - for all thumbnails, to display the full slide for that thumbnail?

2) What is `$Align` as it applies to ThumbnailNavigatorOptions or Slider Options?

3) What is `$Steps` as it applies to ArrowNavigatorOptions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Re 1: Use GoTo() instead of PlayTo()

Please set $SlideDuration to 0

Re 2: What is $Align?

$Alignspecifies the position that the current slide aligns its left side to 'slides' container. It applies to both 'Slider Options' and '$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions'.

Re 3: $Steps for $ArrowNavigatorOptions

It means steps to go for each navigation request.
e.g. given the value of $Steps is 3, when you click the 'right' arrow, it will go through 3 slides.